# Finite group with unique normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

We all know that symmetric group Sn has a unique normal subgroup An for n>4. Is there any classification of finite groups with unique normal subgroup ? By unique I mean non trivial and improper normal subgroups.

Comment: Not without at least invoking the Classification of Finite Simple Groups.

Comment: Using the classification you could describe such groups roughly, but for an exact description you would need to know all irreducible modules of all finite simple groups over all prime fields, together with ass associated second cohomology groups, which is way beyond our present knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

There is a classification of finite *solvable* groups having a unique non-trivial normal subgroup.

**Theorem:** Let $G$ a finite solvable group. If $G$ has a unique nontrivial normal subgroup, then either $G$ is a cyclic $p$-group of order $p^2$, or
$G$ is a semidirect product $G = P \rtimes Q$, where $P$ is an elementary abelian $p$-group and $Q$ is a cyclic group of order $q$, with $p$ and $q$ being distinct primes. Moreover, the action of $Q$ on $P$ is irreducible.